# How do I fix this arduino code ?(DETAILS BELOW)

Tags: arduino

I have an Arduino Mega 2560. I have an LED grounded and connected to pin 12 by breadboard and a switch connected to pin 7 and pin 2 by breadboard. I have written this program so that a button press changes the LED's state between on and off. The components all seem to be working so I believe it is a coding issue. Here's my code:

```
boolean running = false;
boolean ledon = true;
void statechange() {
  if(running == false) {
    running = true;
    ledon = !ledon;
    if(led on) {
      digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
    } else {
      digitalWrite(12, LOW);
    }
    delay(1000);
    running = false;
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  attachInterrupt(0,statechange,CHANGE);
}
```

I don't receive any errors, it just doesn't work, the LED stays off no matter what.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is right?

```csh
if(ledon)
    {
      digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(12, LOW);
    }
```

It looks like "If the LED is ON, turn it ON, otherwise, If the LED is OFF, turn it OFF."

Shouldn't it be:

```csh
if(ledon)
    {
      digitalWrite(12, LOW);
      ledon = false;
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
      ledon = true;
    }
```

If you're using `ledon` to keep track of state, but change the state independently of your if statement, the two could potentially become out of sync. Especially if code somewhere else can change the state of `ledon`.

The other thing that bothers me is this line:  `if(running == false)`

If that is true (e.g. your *hardware?* is not running), then what is the point of trying to change I/O states at that time?

Comment: The variable is flipped before that bit of code, I think.

Comment: @user3102599 I'd implement that once you know what it was changed to... See Edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean ledon = true;

void statechange()
{
    ledon = !ledon;
    digitalWrite(12, ledon ? HIGH : LOW);
}

void setup()
{
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(7, HIGH);

}

void loop()
{
    attachInterrupt(0,statechange,CHANGE);
}
```

Comment: Actually I just want the LED to change state when I press the button, not blink but thanks anyway.

Comment: In this case, your code can be simplified. I'll update my answer.